# IMG Variable Is Not Working For xsl:param name When IMG Parameter Value Is Being Passed Over Url

Tags: xml, image, xslt, graphics, src

I am a beginner of XSLT language ; here I am simply trying to capture the path of image from the URL and replace same in the src attribute for <fo:external-graphic> but interestingly only any variable name starting with **IMG** in the parameter name is not working; below is the example

URL:
http://..*{host-port-path}*..&**imgLogo**=/*PATH*/test.jpg"

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
.
.
<xsl:param name="imgLogo"></xsl:param>
.
<xsl:template match="fooString">
 <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
.
.
.
 <fo:inline><fo:external-graphic src="file:///{$imgLogo}"/></fo:inline>
.
 </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Above one is working when I am hitting the URL and imgLogo is getting replace by /*PATH*/test.jpg in the src but same is not working for below case(s)

URL:
http://..*{host-port-path}*..&**IMG**=/*PATH*/test.jpg"

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
.
.
<xsl:param name="IMG"></xsl:param>
.
<xsl:template match="fooString">
 <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
.
.
.
 <fo:inline><fo:external-graphic src="file:///{$IMG}"/></fo:inline>
.
 </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

---

URL:
http://..*{host-port-path}*..&**IMGLogo**=/*PATH*/test.jpg"

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
.
.
<xsl:param name="IMGLogo"></xsl:param>
.
<xsl:template match="fooString">
 <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
.
.
.
 <fo:inline><fo:external-graphic src="file:///{$IMGLogo}"/></fo:inline>
.
 </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Only changes i am making is changing the name as/with prefix of **IMG**  like
**IMG,
IMGLogo**

Comment: If you think that has anything to do with XSLT then explain and show in detail which XSLT processor you use and how/where you extract URL parameters to then set the XSLT parameters.

Comment: First, variable names are case-sensitive, so if it's declared as `imgLogo` then you can't refer to it as `$IMGLogo` (which your second example attempts to do. Secondly, note that any ampersand appearing in an XML document (including within a URL) has to be written as `&amp;`. (You haven't made it clear how the URLs you show relate to the stylesheet or source document).

Comment: And please don't tell us something is "not working". Tell us exactly how it fails.

Comment: @MichaelKay had updated the second example this is the error i am getting when i am trying to use name as/with prefix of IMG like IMG, IMGLogo org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener.processEvent Image not found. URI: file:///url('file:////.....path.../image.jpg').

Comment: @MichaelKay But when i am using other variables example- imgLogo or LOGO then I am not seeing this error

Comment: Please show us the exact way you set/bind your parameter values, it is not surprising that a final value of e.g. `file:///url('file:////.....path.../image.jpg')` is not going to work as it has at least one `file:///` too much.